# Regular expression to extract email address from another regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I've got a piece of text that contains another regular expression.

Sample text:

```
...<rege>!^.*$!mailto:asdf@adsfsdaf.com!</rege>...
```

What I want to match is:

```
mailto:asdf@adsfsdaf.com
```

This didn't work:

```
    $patterns[] = '/<rege>!\^\.\*\$!(.*)!<\/rege>/';
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have \ inside '' you have to double it like so:

```
$patterns[] = '/<rege>!\\^\\.\\*\\$!(.*)!<\\/rege>/';
```

I also think that you may want this match to be ungreedy because you want to properly capture email even if similar constructs occur in search text multiple times so:

```
$patterns[] = '/<rege>!\\^\\.\\*\\$!(.*?)!<\\/rege>/';
```

Comment: ??? That's not true and if it was it would be for double quoted strings, not single quoted as used by Steve.

Comment: hm.. you are right, it seems that doubling backslash to obtain literal backslash is only necessary before single quote or at the end of the string. But using double backslash anywhere else also gives only one backslash and is more consistent.

Comment: I tried the second one and it worked just fine! Thanks Kamil!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$patterns[] = '/<rege>!\^\.\*\$!([^<]*)!<\/rege>/';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslashes:

```
<?php

$sample = "<rege>!^.*$!mailto:asdf@adsfsdaf.com!</rege>";
preg_match("/<rege>!\\^\\.\\*\\$!(.*)!<\/rege>/",$sample,$matches);

print_r($matches);
?>
```